# Using zookeeper for service discovery of mesos slaves running docker

Tags: docker, apache-zookeeper, mesos, mesosphere, marathon

I am trying to link 2 docker containers using mesos/marathon framework. As I understand there is no way to use the docker link feature in mesos/martahon. So the way to go forward is to use service discovery. Since zookeeper is already used my question is how to use zookeeper for service discovery so that 1 container can talk to another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For service discovery on Mesos/Marathon, you can use a proxy server (see https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/service-discovery-load-balancing.html) or a DNS server that derives settings from Mesos automatically (see https://github.com/mesosphere/mesos-dns).

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: thanks for pointing out mesos-dns..however I am stuck with another issue. How can you use mesos-dns to lookup a hostname port of a service from one docker container to another docker container both running on the same host.

Comment: @user1507003 you can access another docker container using the hostname `<task>.<framework>.mesos` (if you defined `mesos` as the mesos-dns domain). Example if your docker container is running in Marathon: `myapp.marathon.mesos`. It doesn't matter if the containers run on the same host or not.

Answer (score 0):

Although possible I would reconsider using Zookeeper as a centralized KV store for your configuration and services information. You could try to implement a daemon to ask and save data in zookeeper in order to configure your container's config files and live patching, but it's a complex solution (there are examples of this approach in [this post from Pinterest](http://engineering.pinterest.com/post/77933733851/zookeeper-resilience-at-pinterest), or in Hadoop's ZKFailoverController daemon). From my point of view there are more suited solutions as Consul or etcd, with implementations of the daemons as [kelseyhightower/confd](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/confd) or [consul-template](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-template).

Comment: thanks javier let me evaluate what you have suggested.